# Sorting non-numerical lists

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

The `Sort` function will by default sort from lowest to highest.

```
In[1]:= Sort[{3, 1, 4}]
Out[1]= {1, 3, 4}
```

However, if the list contains non-numerical values, it will sort it incorrectly

```
In[2]:= zeroes = {2 Pi - 2 ArcTan[Sqrt[2 + Sqrt[5]]], 
   2 ArcTan[Sqrt[2 + Sqrt[5]]], 2 Pi + 2 ArcTan[Sqrt[2 + Sqrt[5]]]};

In[3]:= zeroes // N
Out[3]= {4.04615, 2.23704, 8.52022}

In[4]:= Sort[zeroes] // N
Out[4]= {4.04615, 2.23704, 8.52022}
```

One could use the `Greater` function as a parameter to Sort and then reverse the input

```
In[5]:= Reverse@Sort[zeroes, Greater] // N
Out[5]= {2.23704, 4.04615, 8.52022}
```

There is no `Lesser` function in Mathematica, but there must be a better way to do this, without converting the data to floats.

Comment: This is shown in the last two examples under Scope on the manual page for [Sort](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sort.html#25625).

Comment: As *Michael E2* states, in the documentation. If you're trying to avoid conversion for say performance, makes no difference, when using e.g. `Less` on expressions, they're evaluated to numeric where possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `Less` is what you can use.

```
list = {2 Pi - 2 ArcTan[Sqrt[2 + Sqrt[5]]], 
   2 ArcTan[Sqrt[2 + Sqrt[5]]], 2 Pi + 2 ArcTan[Sqrt[2 + Sqrt[5]]]};
Sort[list, Less]
```

Or,

```
Sort[list, #1 < #2 &]
```

Or you could use:

```
SortBy[list, N@# &]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sort[zeros// N]
(* {2.23704,4.04615,8.52022} *)
```

Mathematica is doing exactly what it should. You were sorting the *expressions*...

Ah, ninja'd... As *ubpdqn* posted, `SortBy` if you wish to sort (and keep form) of expressions by numeric value.

Comment: +1 not ninja'd...//N vs ,Less...you 'win' by 2 characters (3 if you count my unnecessary space), am ignoring the first argument :-)

Comment: You're not answering the question which specifically asked for a solution without using conversion to floating point precision.

Comment: @jVincent: not sure what your point (if any) is, I state quite clearly use of `SortBy` as also posted by *ubodqn* gives the expressions...not to mention the OP is quite ambiguous re: exactly what form of result is desired.